# Is sensitive a vaild alternative name for the leading tone?

Tags: theory, scales, terminology

I was reading the sample version of *Modern Harmony Step By Step* and one passage caught my eye:

[image]

In the passage above it seems that what is typically referred to as the leading tone is revered to as sensitive. To me the seems odd, but I'm wondering if this is a valid and accepted alternative name for the leading tone and if so why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a mistranslation.

Comment: Also those terms are two words Sub Dominant not subdominant

Comment: @NeilMeyer [they are all one word](http://www.musictheory.net/lessons/23) except for leading tone.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: I don't think you're right: [subdominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdominant) is written as one word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by Matthew Read, this is for sure a translation error. The author as well as the translator are both Spanish speakers (from Argentina and Mexico, respectively). *Subtonic* is of course correct, but *sensitive* is a mistranslation from the Spanish [sensible](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_%28m%C3%BAsica%29) for leading tone.

Comment: That's interesting. Also if you translate the page you linked into English with Google, it will mistranslated the term to sensitive and tender.

Comment: @Dom: Yes, that's the "usual" meaning of the word, and it's probably OK for an automatic translator to make that error, but I really think that there can't be any excuse for a human translator working on a book on music theory. Such a thing would even put me off reading that book ...

Comment: @MattL. that's why I like to read the samples before I buy a book a I find there are a lot of bad music books out there.

Comment: @Dom: If you're looking for a good book on Jazz harmony, I would recommend [The Chord Scale Theory and Jazz Harmony](http://www.amazon.com/Chord-Scale-Theory-Jazz-Harmony/dp/B000M7B65O/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1432456759&sr=8-1&keywords=nettles+graf) by Nettles and Graf.

Comment: _Sensible_ is also the usual French term for leading tone.

Answer (score 3):

Yes sensitive may also have been a translation from French (*"sensible"* or *"note sensible"* for leading tone), the French word *"sensible"* meaning "sensitive".